# I am moving series of div's which is inside the container using jQuery using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, transform, transition

Series of div's which is inside the container. If button click train should move.

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#train").animate({left: "300px"}, 2000);
       });    
     });            
 </script>
```

Comment: And what is not working? please tell us and include all relevant code.

Comment: The use of `button` as a selector means any `<button>` element that is clicked will activate the callback. Will need to see a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is there something specific you are having difficulty with?  Please have a read of [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#train` may need absolute positioning. Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#train").animate({
      left: "300px"
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#train {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Go</button>
<div id="train">Train</div>
```